# submitting xml drodown results

Tags: xml, post, submit, dropdown

Good day all
I am struggling to submit xml results from a dropdown menu. Hoe does it gets submitted and to send my selected dropdown value?
My code is as follow:

```html
<?php
$total =count($xml3->accounts->children()); 
}
$str="<select name='myselection'>";
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
$str= $str . "<option value=".$xml3->accounts->account[$i]->id.">".$xml3->accounts->account[$i]->name. "</option>";
}
$str = $str. "</select>";
echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, guys.
I managed to figure it out. There was not anything wrong with my code. It was just the script not reading it correctly. Not sure what I did differently but its working now. Don't know why one will sit and struggle for weeks without seeing the solution and one day "BAM" there its in front of your eyes all along ;-D